# Report Builder - Field Data as of 2nd Date Parameter not first

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

I am running a set of financial statements where there are two date parameters, start Date (1/1/20) and end date (2/28/20). For the income statement the report sums the data between the start date and end date. For the Balance Sheet I want the data as of the end date (2/28/20), but it pull it as of the start date (1/1/20). I have the income and balance sheet data in the same dataset and would rather not have two datasets.

SELECT *
FROM   CombinedData8
WHERE (CompanyName = @CompanyName) AND (FiscalMonth BETWEEN @FiscalMonth1 AND @FiscalMonth2)

Thank you

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: Is there a way add an expression that pulls the Balance sheet data as of the 2nd date parameter rather than the first?

Comment: This seems like both a [XY problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and the larger problem of writing efficient queries. Presumably your table (or view) contains raw accounting data - which means it needs to be aggregated. The database engine is **far more capable** of doing that. The short is answer is yes - but only if you move the filtering logic for the lower bound into the presentation of your income. Given that the statements have 2 very different purposes and layouts, i have to wonder why you choose this path.

Comment: Understood that this seems odd and would typically be presented in two different reports. The report that I am having an issue with is a snapshot summary report where management selects the Company name and dates and a 1 page report shows balance sheet data, Income data, company data etc all on one page. I could run the BS as a separate dataset within the report but wanted to see if there was a way to use a single dataset. I am also not very experienced on the most efficient use of queries so I might be missing the point.